# how to use session with HttpContext.Current at null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use session but when I call the SetSession method, I see that HttpContext.Current is null, so I get MinValue (from gettor because session property is null) how to fix this issue? because of that, everytime I'm trying to get session variables, it doesn't work, indeed =D it looks I forgot something but...

From the controller I call the SessionManager when user is connecting:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    {
                        var identityUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);

                        if (identityUser.Matricule.IsNotNull() && !identityUser.Matricule.HasValue)
                        {
                            SetAlert("Error");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SessionManager.matricule = identityUser.Matricule.Value;

                            var user = BL.PersonnelBL.GetAll(SessionManager.matricule); 
                            SessionManager.firstName = user.prenom;
                            SessionManager.lastName = user.nom;
                            SessionManager.chainId = user.chaine.chaine;
                            SessionManager.secteurId = user.chaine.secteur.Id;
                            SessionManager.serviceId = user.chaine.service.Id;
                            SessionManager.isAuditor = user.auditTarget.IsNull() ? false : true;
                        }

                        // Redirect to local
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
```

Session manager:

```
public class SessionManager
    {
    public static int matricule
            {
                get
                {
                    object property = GetSession("MATRICULE");
                    if (property != null)
                    {
                        return Convert.ToInt32(property);
                    }
                    return int.MinValue;
                }
                set 
                {
                    SetSession("MATRICULE", value);
                }
            }
}
private static bool SetSession(string key, object value)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Inside Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
...
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="45" />
</system.web>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: enable sessions. If HttpContext.Current is null, then you are probably not doing it in an active session, I mean when there is not an active request. Are you doing parallel processing?

Comment: Where is this code being executed? Within a controller, a service?

Comment: Are you running this in a seperate task/thread? HttpContext.Current does not get copied onto worker threads IIRC.

Comment: @hazimdikeni: thanks. This must work see the first edited post to see all the code :-)

Comment: @JoeMighty This code is in a Separated manager that handle all sessions. See my edit of Question

Comment: @MarvinSmit : thanks. See my initial post, I edited in order to put all the path of the code, This is not in another thread

Comment: Any chance you running this inside unit tests where it fails (i.e. no Http context present)?

Comment: @Marvin: Thanks... so what Can I do, I saw this Manager working in another project, what do I forget in order to run this session from the manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons your `HttpContext.Current` could be`null`:

You are running this code:

- in a `Task` or another background thread;
- from the `Session_End` event;
- in a `HttpModule` or `HttpHandler` that doesn't support sessions (see the [`IRequiresSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate(v=vs.110).aspx) flag interface).

Comment: Thanks. See my question, i've added more code. I didn't use Task, and Session_End neither. Do I have to implement HttpModule on my Sessionmanager in order to make the session work with it? Thanks

Comment: Indeed, from the controller: var matricule = SessionManager.matricule;

Comment: Sorry to ask, but can you show us? Is it always `null` or only in particular circumstances?

Comment: I have got Int.MinValue when I call SessionManager.matricule in this line: BL.PersonnelBL.GetAll(SessionManager.matricule);

Comment: I see your updated code now in the post, the only thing that bothers me is the `async`. Is the controller action `async` too? Try to set it off.

Comment: all my apologies, YES, the controller is async... shame on me :-)