# Session is null in asp.net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a folder name Controller on root directory in asp.net application. Folder has a class name GraphController.cs

In a class i am accessing session using the following code.

`HttpContext.Current.Session["name"]` but the Current Property is null.

Also I set session state in web config still no result.

WebConfig :

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

ASPX :

and here is my code that call the method after a specific interval

```
 $.ajax({
                            url: "RestService.svc/GetSGCData", //"Default.aspx/GetSGCData", 
                            type: "POST",
                            data: "{}",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // we are sending in JSON format so we need to specify this
                            dataType: "json", // the data type we want back.
                            success: function (value) {
                                averageWaitTime = parseInt(value);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/27980302/993547.

Comment: i have check it but issue still not solved.

Comment: How and Where is the session variable created and assigned a value?

Comment: @Thangadurai: It's about `Current`, not even the `Session`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access session in wcf rest service in asp.net. you need to run service in asp.net compatibility mode.

Add following attribute in your webservice class.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class DashboardGraphService : IDashboardGraphService
{
 // class 
}
```

And also add following tag inside `<system.serviceModel>` in `WebConfig` File.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```